# How to space nav buttons equally in Sitefinity radmenu

Tags: css, list, menu, spacing, sitefinity

I have a Radmenu which has 6 buttons in it which need to have equal spacing between them in my horizontal menu. I have managed to get this right using a percentage value but what if someone decides to add another menu button?

Is there a way of aligning my UL menu in the middle of my wrapping DIV and then spacing the buttons equally.

To top this off, the left button needs to be floated left and the rmLast button needs to be floated right, then the buttons needs to be distributed evenly.

Many thanks!
James

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those problems that could be solved with a table in about 20 seconds.

Anyway, the following link might help:

http://joomlapanel.com/joomla-article/joomla-tutorial/247-fixed-a-liquid-columns-with-css-a-jquery-.html

This technique uses a combination or stylesheets and javascript (jQuery) to accomplish this.